# Generating SVG polygons with PHP/HTML gives strange results

Tags: php, svg

I want to render a SVG image, something like a watch.
the viewBox is 1000 x 1000px, so the center/offset is 500,500

The basic html is this:

```
    <div class="imageMap">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs><style>
        .imageMap polygon { fill: red; opacity:0.5; }
        .imageMap polygon:nth-child(2n) { fill: green; }
        </style></defs>
        <image width="100%" height="100%" 
        xlink:href="clear.gif"></image>
        <?php render() ?>
        </svg>
    </div>
```

the php:

```
    function render() {
      $parts=4;
      $arc = 360/$parts; $offsetX=500; $offsetY=500;
      for($i=0; $i < 360; $i += $arc) {
        $x0 = $offsetX;
        $y0 = $offsetY;
        $x1 = cos($i) * 500+$offsetX;
        $y1 = sin($i) * 500+$offsetY;
        $x2 = cos($i+$arc) * 500+$offsetX;
        $y2 = sin($i+$arc) * 500+$offsetY;
        $stringArray[] = '<polygon points="'.$x0.','.$y0.','.$x1.','.$y1.','.$x2.','.$y2.'"/>';
      }
      return implode(PHP_EOL, $stringArray);
    }
```

[image: Part 3+Part 4]

Comment: #-) you are absolutely right: deg2rad($i) did the job! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cos.php) cos and sin take values in radians. You're providing values in degrees and the values are therefore far too big.

You can use [deg2rad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php) to convert from degrees to radians.